# Is it possible to retrieve lists with specific template?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

Is it possible to retrieve lists with template "Custom List" and display it in a jqxListBox or div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a sample code to get you started. The rest end point used in the request below will return lists based on Template 100 (Generic List)

```
 <div id="jqxListBox"> </div>
    <script>
    var webUrl= _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var myList=[];
    myList.push("<ul>");
        $.ajax({
        url: webUrl+"/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate%20eq%20100",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
         $(data.d.results).each(function () {
      myList.push("<li>"  + $(this)[0].Title + "</li>");                         

    });
    myList.push("</ul>");

    $("#jqxListBox").append(myList.join(''));
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thankyou! The only thing i had to modify was the url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate%20eq%20100",

Answer (score 0):

```
SPSiteDataQuery sdq = new SPSiteDataQuery();
sdq.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\" />";//specify template id here
sdq.ViewFields = "<ListProperty Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Physical_x0020_Location\" /><FieldRef Name=\"LinkFilename\" />";
sdq.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\">";
dt = web.GetSiteData(sdq);
```

Comment: This does not show how to list lists of a certain type in a list

Comment: And its server side code, you don't have SPSiteDataQuery CSOM